# PHP Regular Expression match anything except forward slash

Tags: php, regex

I'm going to have 2 different sets of URLS

```
/marketplace/producer/123-producer-name
/marketplace/producer/123-producer-name/5-genre/500-max-price/0-added/newest/1-page
```

I know the regular expression for the second, but for the first one i'm finding it tricky. I'm trying to match the expression, but I want to make sure it doesn't match the second one as well. I'm using the following;

```
/\/marketplace\/producer\/([0-9]+)\-[^\/]/
```

My logic at the end being match every character except a forward slash, which would then mean it's s possible match for the second one. But when I test it, it returns true even with a forward slash. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend using something like a hash at the start and end of your regexp so it's easier to read: `#\/mark....-[^\/]#`

Comment: @Seer Wouldn't you mean `#/mark....\-[^/]#` as the modifier was changed (hence you wouldn't have to escape slashes?)

Comment: @h2ooooooo My mistake, I do indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
/^\/marketplace\/producer\/([0-9]+)-[^\/]+$/
```

Your regex searches for a string **starting with** a **/** followed by **marketplace/producer/** followed by 1 or more digits followed by a **-** followed by one or more characters which is not a **/** and ends there.

I think the problem was with that there was no anchoring character and it matched a substring of the input also. Also you missed the **+** which makes the regex engine look for a single non-forwardslash character.

Comment: Yeah i'm using that exact one and it returns true with and without a forward slash at the end

Comment: @Wasim You want to match `/marketplace/producer/123-producer-name` and don't match `/marketplace/producer/123-producer-name/5-genre/500-max-price/0-added/newest/1-page`, right?

Comment: Ah actually it does work. It returns true when the URL is `/marketplace/producer/123-pro` or `/marketplace/producer/123-pro/` but returns false if anything comes after the last forward slash. This is exactly how I want it. Many thanks for your help

Comment: @Wasim Was it what you wanted?

Comment: @NaveedS yes I wanted to match `/marketplace/producer/123-pro` and `/marketplace/producer/123-pro/` but nothing else unless it's `/marketplace/producer/123-producer-name/5-genre/500-max-price/0-added/newest/1-‌​page`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this regular expression `[^/]+$`. It will match everything after last forward slash.